# Вылетает чат на firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Хочу освоить firebase. Приложение вылетает сразу же после запуска на телефоне. Но если удаляю весь код из onCreate() все работает.
MainActivity:

package com.example.user.messagerfirebase;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton;
import com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

    TextView enter;
    MaterialTextField mtf;
    EditText msgText;
    TextView text;
    ListView list;
    MessageAdapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference references;
    ChildEventListener childEventListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    enter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    mtf = (MaterialTextField) findViewById(R.id.mtf);
    msgText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    references = database.getReference().child("messages");

    if(childEventListener == null) {
    childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
        references.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
  }

    List<MessageClass> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item, messages);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.fab:
            MessageClass message = new 
MessageClass(msgText.getText().toString());
            references.push().setValue(message);
            msgText.setText("");
    }
}
}
```

Log список:

```
                                                                     adb 
09-13 20:31:48.657 26628-26628/com.example.user.messagerfirebase 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.user.messagerfirebase, PID: 26628

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzcnu

at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)

at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)

at
```

com.example.user.messagerfirebase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)

```
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5258)

at
```

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)

```
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)

at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1264)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5413)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

at
```

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:97
    0)

```
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.messagerfirebase"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Ставьте правильные метки к вопросу - метку про Android-studio почти никто не смотрит и, к тому же, она к вопросу никак не относится. А пролема у вас, видимо, в недостающих либах каких-то. Покажите `build.gradle(module app)` файл. Наверное там чего-то не хватает

Comment: Добавил, правда не понимаю что там может быть нужно.

Comment: database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    references = database.getReference().child("messages"); 
    references.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);           
    Насколько я понял ошибка в этих строках.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать последние и одинаковые версии либ `Firebase` - 11.2.0

Comment: Также, возможно, надо добавить ещё и вот это: `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'`

Comment: Пробую добавить версии 11.2.0 и gradle выдает ошибки (31, 13) (28, 13) (29, 13)

Comment: `выдает ошибки (31, 13) (28, 13) (29, 13)` - это предельно неинформативно. Ничего по этому поводу сказать не могу. Покажите, чтоли, `gradle` файл проекта